# Pass custom fields values to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google

I am using this script on display google maps on my wordpress site:

```
<head>
    <script>
    function initialize()
    {
      var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        zoom:5,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap",mapProp);
    }
    </script>          
</head>
```

I have set up two custom fields "fl_long" , "fl"lat" for the longitute and latitude. How do I modify the code above so that the values are taken from the custom fields instead of being hardcoded numbers?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: could someone also please help me with formatting the code? I tried adding 4 spaces and 8 spaces but i can't get it to work! newb :(

Comment: I don't have time for a complete answer right now, but have a look at the [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function.  (You'll probably also want to check out [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Pat J - you took the words right out of my mouth.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that uses `wp_localize_script()`, as suggested by others. It's just a little bit cleaner, since you don't mix your PHP with your JS, and generally a neat way to pass things from the server side to your JavaScript.

First, put the following code either in your plugin or your functions.php (I use a plugin so I named it accordingly, but you can name it whatever you want):

```
function register_plugin_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('my-coordinates-script',
    plugins_url( 'my-plugin/js/using-coordinates-here.js' ),
    'jquery',
    '0.1');

    global $post;
    $fl_lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fl_lat', true); //  "51.508742" or empty string
    $fl_long = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fl_long', true); // "-0.120850" or empty string

    if( !empty($fl_lat) && !empty($fl_long) ) {
        wp_localize_script('my-coordinates-script', 'my-coordinates', array(
                'lat' => $fl_lat,
                'long' => $fl_long
            )
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-coordinates-script', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/js/using-coordinates-here.js' ) );

} // end register_plugin_scripts

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_scripts' );
```

Note that the call to your `wp_localize_script()` must occur between the call to `wp_register_script()` (for the file in which you'll be using those lat-long coordinates generated with PHP), and the call to `wp_enqueue_script()`. This should output something like this in your page source:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var my-coordinates = {"lat":"51.508742","long":"-0.120850"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yourserver/plugins/my-plugin/js/using-coordinates-here.js?ver=0.1'></script>
```

Then inside your JS file you can have your function use the `my-coordinates` object:

```
function initialize() {
    lat = 0;
    long = 0;
    if (typeof my-coordinates !== 'undefined' && my-coordinates.lat && my-coordinates.long) {
        lat = my-coordinates.lat;
        long = my-coordinates.long;
    }
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
```

Feel free to ask questions if something is not clear from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the script to the head with a wordpress hook:

```
add_action('wp_head','your_google_head');

function your_google_head(){
    $fl_lat = get_post_meta($your_post_id,'fl_lat',true);//$fl_lat = 51.508742;
    $fl_long = get_post_meta($your_post_id,'fl_long',true);//$fl_long = -0.120850;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $fl_lat;?>,<?php echo $fl_long;?>),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
  ,mapProp);
}

    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: It's always better to load scripts using `wp_enqueue_script()`. See http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/best-practice-for-adding-javascript-code-to-wordpress-plugin, for instance.

Comment: I actually didn't even know about the wp_localize_script() function.  I've seen many plugins simply mix their PHP and javascript; I thought it was standard practice.

Comment: I only discovered `wp_localize_script()` when I was trying to pass PHP variables to a jQuery script. It's handy.